# Group action on an ultraproduct

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter, say on $\mathbb N$, and suppose we have a set $X$ with a group action by a group $G$ (for instance, one can think of $X$ as an algebraically closed field and $G$ as a Galois group acting on it).

What can we say of the induced $G$-action on the [ultraproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N} X/\mathcal U$ ?

In particular, can we say anything about the subset of fixed elements in terms of the fixed subset $X^G\subset X$ ?

Comment: Let $X^*$ be the ultraproduct. For $g\in G$ you’ll have $$\operatorname{Fix}_{X^*}(g)=\left(\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{Fix}_X(g)\right)/\mathscr{U}\;.$$

Comment: You're welcome.